# How instance is created without calling constructor in java

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I read on Deserializing java object and came to know that,

While deserializing java object, If instance implements the serializable interface, then an instance of the class is created without invoking it’s constructor.

By going through this [link](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue175.html), I came to know Java uses sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory newConstructorForSerialization() method for creating new instance of Class without calling constructor.

Is it creates totally new constructor for deserialization process?

I want to know how object is created without calling its constructor.
How this method actually works, can someone please explain in simple words.

Answer (score 1):

In Java bytecode the constructor is actually a method you call on an already created object. So if you're writing bytecode you can simply skip the second step.

In fact, there are a lot of control flow constructs that you can express in bytecode but that you can't write in Java source code.

Internally, Java serialization is built into the JVM so it can bypass any rules it likes.

This just underscores the difference between Java the programming language (where `new` always invokes the constructor) and Java the platform (where `NEW` is an opcode that pushes an unconstructed instance of the desired type onto the stack).